# PHP Override Variable on Each Page

Tags: php

I have a file that lists a ton of variables, for example:

```
$PAGE_IS_QA = "false";
```

On each page, for example Register/Index.php, a few important variables are listed, again for example

```
$PAGE_IS_QA = "false";
```

I want to be able to change variables on each page and have them overwrite the other file, so if I change a variable on a single page, it will only affect THAT page.

$PAGE_IS_QA is going to be used to display an error if the page is still being tested, but I do not want this happening on every page and so I need to be able to overwrite the variable from false to true on individual pages.

I hope that makes sense?

Comment: What's your question? And why the double qoutes around a boolean value?

Comment: You can already do that, what's the problem?

Comment: I have the file that stores all of the variables included on each page, but if I update it from true to false, it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try calling a variable (in this case $Testing) from the page itself before including the variables file. If $Testing is initialized, overwrite the value of the variable (example: $PAGE_IS_QA);

File with all the variables: **variables.php**

Page that needs to overwrite the variables in variables.php: **index.php**

```
index.php:
<?php

 $Testing = true; 
 include "variables.php";

?>

variables.php:
<?php
  $PAGE_IS_QA = "false";

  if(isset($Testing)){
    $PAGE_IS_QA = "true";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you :)